# Can I use what "headerlines" removes from a CSV as TableHeadings for the table I create from that File?

Tags: formatting, list-manipulation

I am reading in some data from a CSV file that has a line which gives titles to each "column".

**Here is an example:**

```
Entry No,Val1,Val2,Val3,Val4
0,1.01,1.345,5.234,345.45
1,2.456,1.256,250.56,45.027
```

In reality this file has 20 or so values on each line, and therefore 20 column titles on the first line.  I want to display this data in a table, so I first import the file and then display it like so:

```
dataSet1 = Take[Import["data_set_1.csv","CSV","HeaderLines"->1]] 
TableForm[dataSet1]
```

I want to be able to manipulate and plot my data later so I am pretty sure I have to remove the line containing the labels using the "Headerlines->1" option.

I would like the table to display the column titles that were on he first line of the CSV file.  I know that I *could* specify them manually, but I think there should be someway to do this because I deleted them the set using "HeaderLines"

Comment: I believe this question to be related with [this one][1].


  [1]: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/82557/how-to-plot-a-topographic-surface-3d-chart-from-an-excel-matrix-with-headers-as

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data= Import["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=7jJ4e2jW"];
titles = First@data; data = Rest@data;
TableForm[data, TableHeadings -> {None, titles}]
(*Displays the Table *)
(*Do Something with Data*)
ArrayPlot[data]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer.  I was actually asking about putting the titles on the table not on a plot.  Also I tried to use your method of first and rest but It gave me errors.

Comment: @Ajay This answer works perfectly with me. It also produces a table with the desired headings.

Comment: @eldo The answer has been edited since I tried to get that to run I for got that I needed to put None as the row labels in the table.