# Import Excel sheet into 3D array, 1st row and column as x- and y-axis

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics3d

[image]

It might be simple, but for me, it took several hours working on, but still cannot figure out. 
Basically, I'd like to create 3 dimensional list data ({x,y,z}) from excel file, so I can plot them using ListDensityPlot. Any help will be very appreciable.

A similar question was asked before ([link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18460/import-excel-sheet-into-3d-array)), but it does not control over x, y axis, but just a series of integer numbers. Another similar question ([link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/82557/how-to-plot-a-3d-surface-from-an-excel-matrix-using-column-and-row-headers-as-a)) was asked before, but again, it did not thread in to {x,y,z}, but just simple trick with Ticks.

Here is a code I wrote so far, but I can figure this issue out. Any help will be very appreciable.

```
raw = {{"", 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.}, {20., 1., 8., 6., 1., 8.}, {40., 
    7., 7., 0., 0., 0.}, {60., 3., 4., 7., 7., 7.}, {80., 3., 3., 3., 
    3., 3.}, {100., 8., 6., 8., 8., 8.}};
TableForm@raw
data = raw[[#, 2 ;;]] &[Range[2, 6, 1]];
xlist = raw[[1, 2 ;;]]
ylist = raw[[2 ;;, 1]]
TableForm@data

result = Flatten[MapIndexed[{Sequence @@ #2, #1} &, data, {2}], 1];
TableForm@result
Dimensions@result
```

{{1, 1, 1.}, {1, 2, 8.}, {1, 3, 6.}, {1, 4, 1.}, {1, 5, 8.}, {2, 1, 
  7.}, {2, 2, 7.}, {2, 3, 0.}, {2, 4, 0.}, {2, 5, 0.}, {3, 1, 3.}, {3,
   2, 4.}, {3, 3, 7.}, {3, 4, 7.}, {3, 5, 7.}, {4, 1, 3.}, {4, 2, 
  3.}, {4, 3, 3.}, {4, 4, 3.}, {4, 5, 3.}, {5, 1, 8.}, {5, 2, 6.}, {5,
   3, 8.}, {5, 4, 8.}, {5, 5, 8.}}

xlist = {0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.}

ylist = {20., 40., 60., 80., 100.}

data = {{1., 8., 6., 1., 8.}, {7., 7., 0., 0., 0.}, {3., 4., 7., 7., 
  7.}, {3., 3., 3., 3., 3.}, {8., 6., 8., 8., 8.}}

What I am looking for is creating list of {xlist, ylist, data}, not {1~5, 1~5, data}. Attached is the image of the result of not working code.

Comment: Perhaps `Flatten[MapThread[Append, {Outer[List, xlist, ylist], Transpose@data}, 2], 1]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have made a great deal of progress on your problem. You have successfully extracted `raw` from your Excel spreadsheet and created `xlist`, `ylist` and `data`. It can be frustrating trying to manipulate lists but it gets easier with time.

I am going to rename what you had called `data` to `zlist` just to keep me from getting confused. There is a slightly simpler way of deriving `zlist` from `raw` just using `Part`.

```
raw = {{"", 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.}, {20., 1., 8., 6., 1., 8.}, {40., 
    7., 7., 0., 0., 0.}, {60., 3., 4., 7., 7., 7.}, {80., 3., 3., 3., 
    3., 3.}, {100., 8., 6., 8., 8., 8.}};

xlist = raw[[1, 2 ;;]]
ylist = raw[[2 ;;, 1]]
zlist = raw[[2 ;;, 2 ;;]]
```

I will use the name `data` for the input to `ListDensityPlot`. The `Length` of `xlist` and `ylist` is 5, `zlist` is dimensioned {5,5}.

`Table` can be used to generate the `data` to plot except that there is one too many curly brackets. So it will need to be flattened one level.

```
data = Flatten[Table[{xlist[[x]], ylist[[y]], zlist[[x, y]]},
       {x, Range[5]}, {y, Range[5]}], 1]
```

And then

```
ListDensityPlot[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @ Jack LaVigne, Thank you for your help. It is helpful for me. Now, I see how easy it was.